# Why the ideal sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ generated by $(x)$ is free but vanishes at $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider the affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ where $k$ is a field. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the ideal sheaf of Spec$k[x]$ corresponding to the ideal $(x)$. Since $(x)$ is a free $k[x]$-module, $\mathcal{I}$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}k[x]}$-modules of sheaf of rank $1$.

I feel that it is strange because all sections of $\mathcal{I}$ vanish at $0$ so it does not look like "free". Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Your "vanishing at $0$" is "sent to $0$ in the residue field" at the point, which is a much weaker condition than "vanishing in the stalk", which is "sent to $0$ in the stalk" at the point - this means that the sections should vanish in a neighborhood of the point, which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

This is a source of constant confusion when dealing with locally free sheaves of rank one -- they are subsheaves of the (constant, incoherent) sheaf of rational functions, and it can happen that a section of an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ vanishes at a point when viewed as a rational function, but this does not mean that it maps to $0$ under a (local) isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules $\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_X$. Indeed in your case, that isomorphism is division by $x$.

Comment: In the last sentence, you mean division by $x$ or multiply by $x$?